# How to open new browser page on Host from Jenkins that run on VM

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Well the title describes the question, 
Jenkins is installed and run on Ubuntu VM, with Windows as a Host. 
I’m accessing to Jenkins UI through Windows and would like to add a feature that in some stages Jenkins will open a web page of given URL in Windows host, preferred to do it with Chrome.

Update: with @vinWin suggestion, i'm trying to run python + Selenium + Chormedriver script on Windows node, 
the python script is the example code from "Chromedriver", which executes successfully in Windows when I run it in Pycharm, PowerShell and through batch file, meaning I can see the opening of chrome browser and the search in google.

When I try to run it thorugh Jenkins slave in pipeline build, seems that the script is running without errors, but I don't see the browser opening...

Jenkins pipeline:

```
pipeline {
agent {label 'WindowsHost'}
stages {

    stage('Burn Image'){
            steps{
                bat 'wmic computersystem get name'
                bat 'echo %PATH%'
                echo env.PATH
                echo bat(returnStdout: true, script: 'set')
                bat 'python C:\\git\\tester\\dart_framework\\measurments\\webs.py'
            }
    }
}
```

}

in the log there some rows that seems to point out on some run issues...
may permissions or in compatibilities...

*How to attach the log files here ?

Chormedriver Log from Windows agent:

```
[1582176618.238][INFO]: Cannot switch to US keyboard layout - some keys may 

be interpreted incorrectly
[1582176618.238][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --load-extension="C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\scoped_dir9180_1355856553\internal" --log-level=0 --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\scoped_dir9180_1999495287" data:,
[1582176618.439][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:56085/json/version
[1582176618.742][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Response: {
   "Browser": "Chrome/80.0.3987.116",
   "Protocol-Version": "1.3",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36",
   "V8-Version": "8.0.426.23",
   "WebKit-Version": "537.36 (@dc00a510e4c2ae25c4d084cc3d946fc782249224)",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:56085/devtools/browser/b1d2c87f-9e59-4493-835b-a937fe029787"
```

Chromedriver Log when running in Windows enviroment:

```
[1582180734.741][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --load-extension="C:\Users\udiw\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir10612_170753985\internal" --log-level=0 --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\udiw\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir10612_1995928923" data:,
[1582180734.963][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:56688/json/version
[1582180735.267][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Response: {
   "Browser": "Chrome/80.0.3987.116",
   "Protocol-Version": "1.3",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36",
   "V8-Version": "8.0.426.23",
   "WebKit-Version": "537.36 (@dc00a510e4c2ae25c4d084cc3d946fc782249224)",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:56688/devtools/browser/ebb7f495-4c7e-48a3-9900-f7fdea8a8ac8"
```

Comment: Set WIndows machine as Jenkins slave & use Chrome webdriver installed on Windows to launch it?

Comment: @vinWin, that means that I have to install Jenkins on windows machine as well ?

Comment: Not really, just it will be an additional slave node. Related details https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows

Comment: made some progress - when I configured Jenkins windows slave as service in Windows, browser does not launch. Then I've stopped the service and launch the agent with the JNLP file, and the browser did launched through the python script that uses the chromedriver